# сохранение данных с droppable поля в базу данных jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
У меня имеется две колонны, одна - аккордеон состоящий из имен взятых из базы данных и распределенных в алфавитном порядке, вторая - колонна, место куда можно перетаскивать и дропать имена после чего array имен нужно вставить в базy данных, однако я получаю пустой array и не могу придумать как можно сделать это. первая форма которая позволяет перемешать и скидывать имена:

```
<form class="formcss" method="post" action="create3.php">
<fieldset style="background-color:white;">
    <legend style="font-size: 20px;">Add Stuff</legend>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="small-3 large-3 columns">
    <div id="myAccordion">
    <?php for($i=321; $i<347; $i++)
        {
            echo "<h3>".chr($i)."</h3>";
            echo '<ul class="source">'; 
            $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username LIKE '".chr($i+32)."%' ";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);       
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
            {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {  
                    $name= $row["username"];    
                    echo"<li class='ui-state-highlight'>". $name ."</li>";
                }
            } else 
            {
                echo "0 results";
            }                       
            echo '</ul>';                   
        }
    ?>  
    </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="project" class="small-9 large-9 columns">
        <div>
        <label>Leader:</label>
            <ol>
                <li class="placeholder" name="leader[]" <?php if (isset($leader)) echo 'value="'.$leader.'"' ?>>Add leaders and checkers here</li>
            </ol>
        </div>              

        <div class="row">
            <input type = "submit" style="margin-left:300px; width:150px;"  name ="submit" class="button" value = "Create Project" onclick="userSubmitted = true;"/>    
        </div>
    </div>      
</fieldset>
</form>
```

jquery функция:

```
<link href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery-ui/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    var data = {"total":0,"rows":[]};
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var limit = 2;
            var counter = 0;
        $("#myAccordion"). accordion({heightStyle:"content", active: false, collapsible:true});
        $(".source li").draggable({helper:"clone"});
          $("#project ol").droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text())
                    .addClass("project-item")
                    .addClass('dropClass')
                    .appendTo(this);
            }
        }).sortable({
            items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
            sort: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
            }
        });

        $("#myAccordion ul").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).remove();
            },
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: '.project-item'
        });

        $('#box').keyup(function(){
            var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            if(valThis == ""){
                $('.source > li').show();           
            } else {
                $('.source > li').each(function(){
                    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                    (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
                });
           };
        });
    });
</script>
```

И третья форма где я пытаюсь распечатать мой array, для того чтобы проверить, что я имею внутри:

```
<?php
session_start();
//if user haven't sign in will redirect user to login page 
if(empty($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    session_destroy();  
    header("Location: login.php");
}
$_SESSION['leader'] = $_POST['leader'];
require_once('inc/config.php');
ob_start();
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
print_r($_POST['leader']);
?>
</body>
</html>
```